# Rails JSON as dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ios5

I am writing an API in Rails 3 to be read by an iOS app.

I wrote this:

```
def index
  @shops = Shop.all

  render json: @shops
end
```

The output comes out as an array:

```
[{
"created_at": "2012-07-28T10:35:38Z",
"id": 1,
"name": "Shop1",
"phone": "111-111-1111",
"updated_at": "2012-07-28T10:35:38Z"
}]
```

However, I would like my iOS app to read it as a dictionary

How can I turn the JSON output into a dictionary?

Comment: What would you like the result to look like? Should it be a dictionary like `{"shops": [{"created_at": ...}]}`, or something different?

Comment: Yes a dictionary like that exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around a bit but unfortunately couldn't find a way of doing this automatically. For the time being, your best bet would probably be to just do this manually:

```
def index
  @shops = Shop.all

  render json: {:shops => @shops}
end
```